# What do you mean by Export Change in Managed Exensibility Framework?

Tags: mef

I'm new to MEF. In Managed Exensibility Framework, what do you mean by events exportschanging and exportschanged. How one can visualize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Managed Extensibility Framework, objects are wired together by matching imports with exports. I assume you already know about that. (If not, you should read through the [MEF programming guide](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Guide&referringTitle=Documentation) first and play with MEF a bit.)

In a typical scenario, exports are provided by a catalog of types. Some of these catalogs can be changed while the application is running, at which point the application might be [recomposed](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Recomposition&referringTitle=Guide).

Here are two examples of modifying a catalog:

- [`DirectoryCatalog.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.refresh.aspx) (this will rescan the directory and pick up new assemblies)
- [`AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.aggregatecatalog.catalogs.aspx)

When this happens, the `CatalogExportProvider` based on the catalog will trigger the `ExportsChanging` event right before handling the change, and `ExportsChanged` right after.

Not all export providers have to be based on catalogs, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Great! pretty clear now. Thanks. Could you please point me to any other resource where I can get a detail view of MEF other than that at Codeplex or reference MSDN documentation? May be a book title.

Comment: @Morin: nope, there were [plans for a book](http://mef.codeplex.com/discussions/75498?ProjectName=mef) but those got shelved. [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) is working on a book about DI in general which will have a chapter on MEF. For now, the codeplex programming guide is the best MEF reference. You can also take a look at the blogs of [Glen Block](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/) (former MEF PM), [Hamilton Verissimo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hammett/) (current MEF PM), [Daniel Plaisted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/), [Kathleen Dollard](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kathleen/), etc.